# How to create a method for my button to select an item

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I've made my own custom button in visual studio C# using the .NET framework and when I press the label, it lights up the panel behind it but its not a real "Select" feature it just runs the code behind it which is basically (run this script when label is being pressed), my question is, how do I make it so, it waits to start the script until the user presses the Launch button?

[image: Normal Mode]

[image: Selected Mode]

This is what happends when I press the button

```
private void script1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WindowMover();
   AutoItX3 autoit = new AutoItX3();

    autoit.MouseMove(200,50,10);
   // return; USE THIS TO STOP THE SCRIPT
    autoit.MouseMove(500, 20, 50);
    return;




}
```

aswell as

```
    private void script1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        script1Pan.BackColor = Color.Empty;
        script2Pan.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#363535");
    }
```

Comment: Im not asking for code, im asking what type of way should I approach this?

Comment: show us the code you have tried, showing image is not enough

Comment: In the 'Script X' OnClick handler, load the script path into a private member string var of the form.  In the 'Launch' OnClick, check the string.  If it's empty, do nothing, if not, execute the script and clear the string.

Comment: Pretty pictures, however, if you need it to do more, you need to tell it to do more.

Comment: Without any code its impossible to tell something. Infinite possible answers...

Comment: Added some extra code its very basic

Answer (score 0):

You can add a handler to your Button class

```
public handler EventHandler Script;
public PerformScript()
{
    if (Script != null)
        Script(this, EvenArgs.Empty);
}
```

Then you can sign your scripts to buttons in form constructor

```
button1.Script += script1_Click;
button2.Script += script2_Click;
```

When you click a button you just remember which button was clicked last

```
private MyButton selectedButton = null;
private void anyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is MyButton)
        selectedButton = (MyButton)sender;
}
```

And finally, when you press Launch button you call

```
if (selectedButton != null)
    selectedButton.PerformScript();
```